# Autoconfigure M365 outlook profile

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, exchange

**I am trying to find a way to autoconfigure outlook profiles in M365 office apps.** I can do this if the client is using microsoft for exchange by using Intune's admin templates to push out a custom GPO that autoconfigures an email based on AD smtp address. However this wont work for my clients who have an office apps license but use exchange with a different provider.

I saw a good post on using the office customization tool here: [configuring Outlook with powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/1141519/configuring-outlook-with-powershell)

**However** that only works for office 2016 and below. I am looking for anything that works for M365 office apps.

**What I have looked into:**

I tried using Microsoft's website for the new office customization tool here: https://config.office.com/deploymentsettings

However that doesn't have the option to setup email profiles like the old one did.

I tried using Intune's administrative templates to push out a GPO that autoconfigures profiles based on AD smtp address. The problem with this is that Azure is the AD and it doesn't know where my emails live. (My emails live with intermedia/serverdata servers)

I have heard that you export profile from the registry of an already setup computer. However I would need the registry setup of a new person so I don't have to create the profile from scratch on another computer first. Like, if there was a script that can generate an outlook profile for the registry based on the name, email, type of email (exchange), and server address, that would be awesome!!!

Any ideas would be appreciated.

**I don't have enough rep points for pictures so here are links to my pictures**
https://i.ibb.co/jftNVg2/help1.png
https://i.ibb.co/8ggz5hg/help2.png

Comment: I just setup my autodiscover and Outlook pretty much configures everything automatically. The user just needs to enter in their email address and their password, and then next, done, and the rest just works on it's own. Seems like overkill otherwise since this is what autodiscover is for so if you haven't already or don't have some weird constraint preventing getting autodiscover setup and configured will simplify this for your end users so you don't have to do the overkill automation of trying to auto configure Outlook via script, GPO, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[ZeroConfigExchange](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/outlook-global-customer-service/zeroconfigexchange-automating-the-creation-of-an-outlook-profile/ba-p/389691) sounds to be a little bit related to your issue. But I'm afraid it might not work as well due to the reason

> However this wont work for my clients who have an office apps license
> but use exchange with a different provider.

as you mentioned.

If this do fails as well, I'm afraid that manually configuring your email accounts is a process that cannot be skipped.

Comment: Actually someone named Dmitry who's in Microsoft MVP created some tools that would allow me to automate the process but I would have to script out the program in either C#, vba, or python. However my com knowledge is very very limited, so I'm trying to learn more of an understanding of calm and then by Dimitris product so I can automate the process. If it works I will let everyone know and if I'm allowed to release it I'll release it for other people to use.

Comment: It would be so nice of you to share your update with us here. Warm regards.